# How to place the camera so that it shows a 2d area of variable size in full?

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine

I'm making an application that generates a 2D area (you can think of it as a drawing), with a camera hovering over it. The size of said drawing isn't known in advance, and could change greatly. After the "drawing" is generated, I want to position the camera so that the whole drawing is in view.

My original idea was to calculate the points that are at the top, bottom, left, and right of the drawing and having the camera move back, "zooming out" until they are all in sight, but there has to be a better way, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are working in 2D (thus orthographic camera mode), you can set the `camera`'s `orthographicSize`:

```
Camera.main.orthographicSize = height / 2F; //half of the height of the area
```

Then, set the `aspect` ratio (width / height):

```
Camera.main.aspect = 1F; //for example, a square area
```

Comment: I think that could work. If I wanted to maintain a fixed aspect ratio, would it be enough to just take either height or width depending on which one is larger?

Comment: @kace91 For a fixed aspect ratio, set the aspect ratio first. Then just change the `orthographicSize`, which is the half-height. No need to bother about the width, it will scale automatically given the aspect, and the height (which is the orthographicSize)

Comment: I mean that, if the drawing happens to be much wider than it is tall, then considering just the height could leave parts of the drawing out of view couldn't it?

Comment: @kace91 if ur drawing has a height of 10 units and a width of 200 units, set the orthographic size to 10, and the camera aspect to 20. This will ensure that your camera will see the whole drawing.